# split a value from a range of column and color the duplicate value using vb macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the bolow requirement of which i had achieved few but still i need some help

1. If the status in G column = ready to retest or passed
2. Then if there are any values in Column C, take/split the Duplicate ID in column C separated with comma(,)
3. Search the duplicate id in Column A and mark it with Green color

[![Example Data][1]][1]

ex. In Row 1 for the defect ID CMS-921 there are 2 duplicate id 44 and 163693. so i need to look for those values in Column A.

4. If the status of those defects (44 and 163693) is NOT closed then i need to mark the entire row in Green color

Example of my current code:

```
Sub findduplicateColorIt()
Get the last row
Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet2")                                       
lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lastRow
 For j = 2 To lastRow
    If Report.Cells(i, 4).Value <> ""_
       And Report.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Ready   to retest"_
       And Report.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Jira" Then 

'This will omit blank cells at the end 
'(in the event that the column lengths are not equal).

        If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 2).Value, Report.Cells(i, 3).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

' need to get a logic where i need to get value from Colum D, 
'split it and find the value in column A and color the row with green/any.

            a = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
            For Text = 0 To UBound(a)
            MsgBox a(Text)
            Next Text

            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    End If
 Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you having issues with doing? (finding duplicates, splitting values, the for loop isn't working, etc.)

Comment: Looks like you have an `Else` that is not doing anything.

Comment: @CodyG. now array a = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")  is having multiple values, now i need to take individual value from a(i) and search it in Column B and color the entire row.. I am not able to get the logic for that...

Comment: Update

I got the splited value in a(text), now all i need is look for that value in column B and highlight the row with Green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venkat ... use this as an example of the logic. You will need to add things to avoid / capture errors, I am sure.

```
Sub findduplicateColorIt()
Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim a() As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long, chkRow As Long

Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet3")
lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Report.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" And _
        (InStr(Report.Cells(i, 7).Value, "Ready to retest") > 0 Or _
         InStr(Report.Cells(i, 7).Value, "Passed") > 0) And _
        InStr(Report.Cells(i, 1).Value, "JIRA") > 0 Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.

        a = Split(Report.Cells(i, 3).Value, ",")
        For j = 0 To UBound(a)
            chkRow = Report.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Find(a(j)).Row
            If chkRow > 0 Then
                If Not InStr(Report.Cells(chkRow, 7).Value, "Closed") > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print Report.Range("A" & i).Address
                    Report.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code it worked as i wanted,, just changed few things below

                chkRow = Report.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Find(a(j)).row
            Debug.Print Report.Range("B" & chkRow).Address
            If chkRow > 0 Then
                If Not InStr(Report.Cells(chkRow, 7).Value, "Closed") > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print Report.Range("A" & a(j)).Address
                    'Report.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    Report.Range("A" & chkRow).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If
            End If